# How to center 2 edit texts and a button below horizontally

Tags: android

I want to achieve the following look for a login activity, but it looks quite different on different devices I'm testing.

[center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlFjV.jpg)

Edit: This is the current code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailField"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordField"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see on the design tab it looks ok, but I can't move it up or down, and on different devices it's not exactly centered:
[Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8pjm.jpg)

Comment: How does it look on your devices? What code are you using? Show us to help you

Comment: I added the coed and image of the code, I can't move it up or down as I wish, it's stuck up there

Answer (score 2):

add the views in a constraint layout and add a horizontal guideline at the percentage of the screen that you want your views to begin. Then just constrain your views underneath that, one after the other, and constrain their sides to match the parent:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
       />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailField"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordField"
      />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This should be the approach. Its the right and most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: from some reason when  I copy paste it the view is blank (nothing appears in the design tab)

Comment: But the guideline you mentions talks aboust the percentage of height, I was talking about making the text views at width of 70% for example

Comment: sometimes you need to build the project first, before anything appears on the design tab. Also, the guidelines can be horizontal or vertical, just change the orientation attribute and adjust the percentage. If the line changes orientation though, the views that are constraint by it, will need to be adjusted as well

Answer (score 0):

How about a `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailField"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordField"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible to "play" with the width of the button and edit texts as percentage? for example if I want the width of the button and the edit texts to be 70 percent of the width, what can I do?